# How to actually limit or cut a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: pyspark

I am implementing a data warehouse, and I have a data frame that is shows all of the user rows that have changed between my data source and my data warehouse.  Unfortunately, I cannot process all 70k changed rows, due to other constraints.  What I want to do is to cut the changed rows frame, taking the first or random 10k rows.  However, when I do this I get unpredictable results.  The next 3 operations on the frame are selecting different rows.

```
changed_rows = source_rows.join(dim_rows,
                                on=source_rows.user_id=dim_rows.user_id,
                                how='inner')
     .filter((source_rows.user_name != dim_rows.user_name)
             | (source_rows.user_email != dim_rows.user_email))
     .limit(5)
print(f"Found {changed_rows.count()} rows")
old_rows = changed_rows.select(dim_rows["*"])
new_rows = changed_rows.select(source_rows["*"])
```

So the code without the `limit(5)` works, finding 70k changed rows. But when I print out the `old_rows` and `new_rows`, they have different user_ids.  They are supposed to be matching rows with the same user_id.

Essentially, my `join().filter()` produces a lot of rows, and I want to take the first N or a random N rows from changed_rows, and discard the rest.  They will get processed on the next run.

However, it seems that each subsequent operation selects 5 random rows out of 70k.

As a test, I changed from `.limit(5)` to `.filter(source_rows.user_id < 100)`, and then I get a consistent subset of user ids in all subsequent frames.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The help on https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/ gives following example. You are using to select dim_rows\source_rows["*"]. I would think you want to use `col` as shown below.

```
empDF.alias("emp1").join(empDF.alias("emp2"), \
col("emp1.superior_emp_id") == col("emp2.emp_id"),"inner") \
.select(col("emp1.emp_id"),col("emp1.name"), \
  col("emp2.emp_id").alias("superior_emp_id"), \
  col("emp2.name").alias("superior_emp_name")) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```